# Postgres epoch date as varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, epoch, alter

So I've been given a lovely little database. One of the tables in the database (several million rows large) has this column:

```
time_in character varying(255)
```

Stored in there is an epoch timestamp. What is the most sane way I can convert this to a proper epoch timestamp column without losing data?

Answer (score 1):

First off there is no separate `epoch timestamp` datatype so the type you want to convert to is just regular timestamp. In the [PostgreSQL Documentation - ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html) there's an example that fits to your case almost perfectly (I just added a cast to `integer`):

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ALTER COLUMN time_in SET DATA TYPE timestamp with time zone
    USING
        timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + time_in::integer * interval '1 second';
```

Note that the conversion might take some time and will produce an error if all of the rows are not valid epoch times.

Answer (score 0):

Or, [quoting the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html):

> A single-argument `to_timestamp` function is also available; it accepts
>   a `double precision` argument and converts from Unix epoch (seconds
>   since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00) to `timestamp with time zone`. (`Integer`
>   Unix epochs are implicitly cast to `double precision`.)

```
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN time_in
  SET DATA TYPE timestamptz USING to_timestamp(time_in::float8);
```

But first, decide whether `timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`) or `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`) is the better choice for you:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)